# Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebApplication4.SqlConnection' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' ~AddUser.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have tried so many types I don't know how to insert.

Is there any problem with sql server?

PLEASE HELP ME FAST..

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=localhost/SQLEXPRESS.Polaris.dbo;Initial Catalog=Polaris;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    //string s1 = "insert into Login values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Login values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "'");
    cmd1.Connection = con;
    rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    Label2.Visible = true;
    //EndEventHandler.RemoveAll();
 }

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: Where in the code are you getting this error

Comment: isn't it obvious... u r using `ExecuteReader` for `insert`. Use `ExecuteNonquery` for insert

Comment: I hope for you that at no one of your users comes to mind to type in textbox1 the following string `Steve'); DROP TABLE Login; --`

Comment: i tried it also... but its not working error ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebApplication4.SqlConnection' to
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

According to error you have class called SqlConnection in WebApplication4 namespace. You may have mistakenly generate that class. you need to remove that class first and then add reference to  `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: I am getting error for con.open() like - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=localhost/SQLEXPRESS.Polaris.dbo;Initial Catalog=Polaris;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string s1 = "insert into Login values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s1, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\MLV\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\AddUser.aspx.cs 27 30 AutomatedTest

Comment: @VishwanathMagge: you didn't actually use the posted code, because if you did, you would not be getting that error.